# Angular usa o pattern MVVM?

Tags: angular, design-pattern, mvvm, viewmodel

Tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao design do *framework* Angular

- O *framework* realmente usa MVVM por completo ou somente alguns princípios?
- Component é inteiramente um ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O framework realmente usa MVVM por completo ou somente alguns princípios?

Há controvérsias, algumas pessoas acham que é mais ou menos, outros dizem que algo bem diferente e que ele é um CBA (Compoente Based Arqchitecture).

> Component é inteiramente um ViewModel?

Não, uma *viewmodel* é usada por um componente como base de dados para fazer o que ele sabe fazer, como é no MVVM. O *viewmodel* é usado para fazer o *binding*.